# The local function 'OnTriggerEnter2D' is declared but never used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know how to fix it. It's a 2D game. When you collide with the box, it should load/teleport you to the next scene, but it doesn't.

I tried everything on the internet and it didn't work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class VictoryZone : MonoBehaviour 
{        
    public void LoadNextLevel() 
    {
        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
        {   
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to teleport me to my next level.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you nested the `OnTriggerEnter2D()` function inside of `LoadNextLevel()`? That's what the [Local Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) warning is referring to.

Those should be two separate functions, not one within the other. `OnTriggerEnter2D()` is a function of MonoBehavior; the MonoBehavior (VictoryZone) is what gets notified of the collision.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class VictoryZone : MonoBehaviour {

    public void LoadNextLevel() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
        LoadNextLevel();
    }

}
```

Note: you might also need to check the GameObject associated with `collider` to make sure that it's a player, and not an enemy or something (if, hypothetically, you had enemies or projectiles or other objects with colliders moving into the victory zone).

Comment: I hope God gives you anything you ask for